# How to show frontend demo from WordPress customizer options?

Tags: wordpress, demo, theme-customizer

I am making a WordPress Woocommerce theme using Kirki Customizer. For the default archive page, there are different product card styles and girds. But using the customizer, I can only show demo one the archive page for one option only. But I also want to show other options like this one
https://klbtheme.com/medibazar/shop/?opt=right-sidebar
But I don't know how to show this using get parameter.
Can anyone help?

I have created customizer options. But I want to show demos using customizer options